# No puedo hacer una solicitud curl en la consola

Tags: mercadopago, consola, curl

Estoy intentando hacer una solicitud curl en la consola para poder crear usuarios de prueba en mercado pago, pero me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> En línea: 4 Carácter: 47
> + "https://api.mercadopago.com/users/test_user" \
> +                                               ~
> Token '\' inesperado en la expresión o la instrucción.
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
> Este es el curl;
> curl -X POST \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
> -H 'Authorization: Bearer PROD_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
> "https://api.mercadopago.com/users/test_user" \
> -d '{"site_id":"MLU"}'
> ```

Comment: PowerShell no usa un backslash \ para continuar un comando en otra línea sino un backtick \`

Answer (score 0):

Quizás sea tarde pero por si le sirve a alguien. En una consola de comandos, terminal o *powershell* donde tengan instalado *cURL*

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.mercadopago.com/users/test_user?access_token=ACA_TU_ACCESS_TOKEN" -d "{"site_id":"MLA"}"
```